# Does anybody know what this electronic component is?

Tags: components, identification

I have an electronic component which has no letter or number on it. It has 2 legs and when you shake it there is something moving inside up and down. I am searching for it for hour still have no clue. Here is the photo I've just taken:

[image]

Comment: A size reference in the photo or just telling us the dimensions would help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a tilt switch.
It has a ball in it which breaks a contact when it rolls away or moves away from contacts.
Try measuring the resistance with it in various orientations

The image below is copied [from here](http://www.mindsetsonline.co.uk/product_info.php?products_id=261)

[image]

[This page](http://cnmat.berkeley.edu/resource/tilt_switch) says about one similar:

- Tiny tilt switch type BT411-2 has a built in rolling ball (instead of mercury) so it doesn’t have the environmental health hazards that mercury tilt switches have.
- These and similar types are used in vibration car alarms, sneakers that blink, toys, etc.

[image]

---

[Many here](http://www.comus-intl.com/products/prods.asp?Cat=Tilt/Tip-Over%20Switches%20-%20Non%20Mercury)

---

Re your link:

> Strøm: 2mA maks.
>   Størrelse: housing Ø5.2 × 14mm (leads + 15mm)
>   Maks. temperature: 100°C
>   non-active contact: 10 Mohm
>   active contact: +/- 5 ohm

2 mA current rating.
10 megohm open circuit
5 Ohms operated.
5.2 mm dia x 14mm long with 15mm leads.
Maximum temperature 100 C.

Comment: thnx i guess it is

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a crystal oscillator , probably the 32.768Khz. Where did you get it from ?

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/540

Comment: I think this is incorrect because crystals don't rattle when you shake them. Also, it looks like one wire is connected to the can, which would be very unusual for a 2-pin crystal.  In any case, a 2-pin device isn't going to be a oscillator.  At best is would be a bare crystal. I think Russell is on the right track, so -1 for this answer and +1 for his.